# delete db entry after unlink

Tags: php, upload

Apologies in advance if this question is malformed or a bit thick but here goes...

I have a php form wh reviews data entry

One part of it deals w uploaded files.

There are 3 checkboxes for three possible files that can be uploaded per table row. There are 3 fields in the db relating to these possible file uploads. Ticking the form checkboxes causes the corresponding uploaded files to be unlinked. It works fine.

Here's my puzzle. How do I delete/update the right entry in the db corresponding to the unlinked file(s)?

The problem is the 3 checkboxes are named the same in the html: 'delpic[]'. Values returned by ticking the checkboxes, in other words, are plonked into an array. This is key to managing the unlinking succinctly (I think).

If just one file for a particular row is to be unlinked, how can the app 'know' the corresponding field in the mysql db to update ?

Argghhh.

Tom

Comment: please refrain from abbreviating regular english words unnecessarily. not everyone speaks the same language you do.

Comment: Application knows nothing. It just execute the algorithm **you** wrote. What prevents you from populating filename into checkbox value?

Comment: Apologies as well then for abbreviations.

Comment: The checkbox values are populated by the uploaded filename. If just one of the three checkboxes is ticked, one value is returned. That's enough information to do the unlink operation correctly, but not enough to identify which table field should be updated.

Answer (score 0):

How it will 'know' is that you will tell it in your script using the proper query.  Say that the you have a field, 'file_names',  in the database table, 'table', that store unique filenames and all your files in an associated directory have unique names.  Then when you do something to file 'foo', you will query your table and look at the row that has 'foo' in if and do somethig to hat row using the proper sql.  like deleting that row for, for instance.

```
$db = mysql_connect('YOUR_DB_ADDRESS','YOUR_DB_USER','YOUR_DB_PASS') or die("Database error"); 
mysql_select_db('YOUR_DB', $db); 

$SQL = 'DELETE FROM table WHERE file_names = "foo"';
mysql_query($SQL);
```

Comment: Yes but your SQL query deletes the whole row. I would like to do an update operation. My example posits a table with 3 fields to record the urls of uploaded files. To change one uploaded file means deleting it, a replacement upload, and updating the url which records the file location. Using checkboxes in a form to choose which already uploaded file to replace seems to be a dead-end. There is no obvious way to get from the unlinking operation to the now orphaned url.

Answer (score 0):

In your form, you're using arrays.  I'm guessing these arrays hold the name of the files you want to delete, such as below?

```
<?php
array => (
    [0] => 'file1.gif',
    [1] => 'file2.gif',
    [2] => 'file3.jpg'
    // ...
)
?>
```

I'd personally recommend that you use the primary keys from the database here instead of the file names (your DB table *does* have a primary key, right?), and then fetch the rows from the database.  That way you know that the rows exist, and you'll be able to get the filenames from the table.

As for the actual deletion, if your database supports transactions, then I'd be more inclined to do it the other way around and delete the rows before the files, with the following pseudocode:

1. Start a transaction
2. Delete the row from the database
3. Attempt to delete the file
4. if (row deleted) and (file deleted)
5. Commit transaction
6. else
7. Roll back transaction and report error

Comment: Thanks. Starting fr the other end - updating the file url in the table first - is more sensible. I ended up where I was and wondered if there was a way out. There is not: I am stuck, so time to rethink along yr lines.